# Implement a Java interface method with a variable number of args in Clojure

Tags: interface, proxy, clojure

I know that I implement a Java interface in Clojure using proxy like this:

```
(def print-element-handler
  (proxy [DefaultHandler] []
    (startElement [uri local qname atts]
      (println (format "Saw element: %s" qname)))))
```

Note that there are four args, *[uri local qname atts]*, for the four args in the interface method, *startElement*.

Suppose a method in a Java interface has a variable number of args like this:

```
List<Task> getTasks(Object... args);
```

What do I put for the arg list in the corresponding Clojure function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not 100% certain, as I am not able to test it out at the moment, but I believe the answer is you just have a single parameter for the array. I know for a fact that when you call a Java method with varags, you have to convert the Clojure collection into an array before passing it in. I imagine it's no different here.

For an example, here is the source for [`format`](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/format):

```
(defn format
  "Formats a string using java.lang.String.format,
   see java.util.Formatter for format string syntax"
  {:tag String
   :added "1.0"}
  [fmt & args]
  (String/format fmt (to-array args)))
```

Comment: Right. So you do something like `(reify TheInterface (getTasks [this tasks] (doseq [task tasks] (...))))`. The Object[] that `tasks` really is, at the bytecode level, is just a single parameter. Then in the implementation you treat it like any other seq.