# How to handle java variable length arguments in clojure?

Tags: clojure, variadic-functions, clojure-java-interop

I'am wrapping a java lib into clojure, but i have problems dealing with variable length arguments. Say,

```
TestClass.aStaticFunction(Integer... intList){/*....*/}
```

How could i call this function in clojure?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Implement a Java interface method with a variable number of args in Clojure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9103777/implement-a-java-interface-method-with-a-variable-number-of-args-in-clojure)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Since Java varargs are [actually arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html), you can call vararg functions in Clojure by passing an array.

You could convert a Clojure seq (maybe by using Clojure's variety of variable argument functions) into an array:

```
 (TestClass/aStaticFunction (into-array Integer [(int 1),(int 2)]))
```

or

```
(defn a-static-function-wrapper [& args]
  (TestClass/aStaticFunction (into-array Integer args))
```

Or make an array and set its indices manually

```
(TestClass/aStaticFunction (doto (make-array Integer 3)
                              (aset 0 first-element)
                              (aset 1 second-element)
                              (aset 2 third-element)))
```

Answer (score 9):

Java variable length arguments actually want an array as input.

So in Clojure the call should be something like:

```
(TestClass/aStaticFunction (into-array Integer some-sequence-of-integers))
```

Answer (score 5):

```
(TestClass/aStaticFunction (to-array '(1 2 3 4 5)))
```

For e.g.

```
(java.util.Arrays/asList (to-array '(1 2 3 4 5)))
```