# Can't call createTempDirectory in Clojure

Tags: java, clojure

Code in clojure:

```
(import '(java.nio.file Files))
(Files/createTempDirectory "Test")
```

There is error:

```
CompilerException java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching method: createTempDirectory, compiling:xxxx
```

But in java's doc http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createTempDirectory(java.lang.String,%20java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...)

There is an String parameter for `createTempDirectory`, I'm using java 1.7.0

Comment: when calling java method with variable arguments from clojure, you cannot omit the variable argument. you have to give array of `FileAttribute` as second argument, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11702184/how-to-handle-java-variable-length-arguments-in-clojure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this code:

```
(java.nio.file.Files/createTempDirectory "Test"
  (into-array java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute []))
```

As @ymonad mentioned, you cannot omit the variable argument when calling java method with variable arguments. If you don't want to specify the `FileAttribute`, just pass the empty array of the type.