# Using lmdbjava in Clojure

Tags: java, clojure, lmdb

I'm trying to use lmdbjava in Clojure, but I'm struggling.

```
(import '[org.lmdbjava Env])
(def path (clojure.java.io/file "/tmp"))
(.open (.setMaxDbs (.setMapSize (Env/create) 10485760) 1) path)
```

(p.s. I realise there are cleaner ways. This is just for testing purposes.)

This is the error:

```
IllegalArgumentException No matching method found: open for class java.lang.Class  clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod (Reflector.java:53)
```

I've also tried this:

```
(.open (.setMaxDbs (.setMapSize (Env/create) 10485760) 1) path org.lmdbjava.EnvFlags/MDB_NOLOCK)
```

and this:

```
(.. (Env/create) (setMapSize 10485760) (setMaxDbs 1) (open path org.lmdbjava.EnvFlags/MDB_NOLOCK))
```

And I get this error:

```
ClassCastException org.lmdbjava.EnvFlags (in module: Unnamed Module) cannot be cast to [Lorg.lmdbjava.EnvFlags; (in module: Unnamed Module)  user/eval1339 (form-init2868059116743223586.clj:1)
```

I realise I'm probably doing something daft, because I'm new to both Java and Clojure. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

By the way, this is the tutorial I'm following:

https://github.com/lmdbjava/lmdbjava/blob/master/src/test/java/org/lmdbjava/TutorialTest.java

Thanks!

Comment: Can you start from the beginning, so see if there's a problem with `(Env/create)`? Also does `.setMapSize` return an object? From your code it would have to. Do things one at a time with intermediate *variables*, and use `_ (println intermediate-var)`. Also `(type intermediate-var)` for each step would be handy.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I did try breaking it up into intermediate steps when debugging. It was the .open part that was causing me problems. I also originally used 'doto', but rewrote it this way to try and make sure that it matched the tutorial as much as it possible.

I used 'type' and also tried to do inspection when I was debugging this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the signature of the  [Env.Builder](http://static.javadoc.io/org.lmdbjava/lmdbjava/0.6.0/org/lmdbjava/Env.Builder.html) class:

```
Env<T>  open(File path, int mode, EnvFlags... flags)
```

you also have to supply a [EnvFlags varargs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) parameter. This is how you do it in Clojure:

```
(.open (.setMaxDbs (.setMapSize (Env/create) 10485760) 1) path (into-array org.lmdbjava.EnvFlags []))
```

Also see [How to handle java variable length arguments in clojure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11702184/how-to-handle-java-variable-length-arguments-in-clojure)

Comment: @user989266 your should accept his answer if it does the job.

Comment: Apologies, this is the first stackoverflow question I've posted. I assumed I just needed to upvote it.

Comment: Oh, it was that greyed-out tick? What a crappy interface.