# No matching method found with JDBI and Clojure

Tags: clojure, jdbi

I have a simple DAO ns:

```
(ns   alavita.dao
  (:require
    [clojure.tools.logging    :as     log     ]
    [clojure.java.io          :as     io      ]
  )
  (:import
    [org.jdbi.v3.core Jdbi Handle]
  ))

(defn create
  (^Jdbi [^String url]
    (Jdbi/create url))
  (^Jdbi [^String url ^String username ^String password]
    (Jdbi/create url username password)))

(defn open
  ^Handle [^Jdbi jdbi]
  (.open jdbi))
```

When trying to use the lib:

```
alavita.core=> (def c (dao/create "jdbc:sqlite:/tmp/data.db"))
#'alavita.core/c
alavita.core=> (def h (dao/open c))
#'alavita.core/h
alavita.core=> (.execute h "show tables")

IllegalArgumentException No matching method found: execute for class org.jdbi.v3.core.Handle  clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod (Reflector.java:53)
```

This is kind of weird because h definitely has .execute:

```
alavita.core=> (cli/all-methods h)
(.attach .begin .close .commit .createBatch .createCall .createQuery .createScript .createUpdate .execute .getConfig .getConnection .getExtensionMethod .getStatementBuilder .getTransactionIsolationLevel .inTransaction .isClosed .isInTransaction .isReadOnly .lambda$attach$3 .lambda$new$0 .lambda$useTransaction$1 .lambda$useTransaction$2 .prepareBatch .release .rollback .rollbackToSavepoint .savepoint .select .setConfig .setConfigThreadLocal .setExtensionMethod .setExtensionMethodThreadLocal .setReadOnly .setStatementBuilder .setTransactionIsolation .useTransaction)
```

Not sure where it goes sideways.

Types for open and create:

```
alavita.core=> (type (dao/create "jdbc:sqlite:/tmp/data.db"))
org.jdbi.v3.core.Jdbi
alavita.core=> (type (dao/open c))
org.jdbi.v3.core.Handle
```

Adding reflection:

```
alavita.core=> (set! *warn-on-reflection* true)
true
alavita.core=> (.execute h "show tables")
Reflection warning, /private/var/folders/nr/g50ld9t91c555dzv91n43bg40000gn/T/form-init767780595230125901.clj:1:1 - call to method execute can't be resolved (target class is unknown).

IllegalArgumentException No matching method found: execute for class org.jdbi.v3.core.Handle  clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod (Reflector.java:53)
```

Comment: Your type hints say that `open` accepts a Jdbi, and returns a Handle, but the error and the fact that it's resorting to reflection suggests that `jdbi` already *is* a Handle. The error mentions `open`, not `.exexute`.

Comment: Verify what `Jdbi/create` returns.

Comment: Hmm, never used that API, but your usage seems correct after looking over the docs. I'd do some pre/post type checks in `open`.

Comment: @Carcigenicate you right i have a copy paste fail. It is actually execute that it has the problem with. I fixed it.

Comment: Ahh, I know what this is. It's because `execute` uses var args. Let's see if I remember how to fix this...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle java variable length arguments in clojure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11702184/how-to-handle-java-variable-length-arguments-in-clojure)

Comment: It's not that it can't find `execute` on the `Handle`, it can't find an `execute` signature that matches the arguments you've given it.

Comment: You are saying execute takes at least 1 argument and potentially more? public int execute(String sql,Object... args) Not sure how can i use it with one in this case than.

Comment: `(.execute h "show tables" (into-array []))` should work. This is probably the most unfortunate Java interop case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [this port](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11702184/3000206), this is an issue with how Java handles var-args. You need to wrap var-args in an array first instead of relying on the var-arg behavior.

I recommend writing a Clojure function to handle this:

```
(defn execute [^Handle h, ^String sql, & args]
  (.execute h sql (into-array Object args)))
```

And using that instead.

Comment: Funnily enough i just repeled it out.(.execute h "show tables" (into-array []))

Comment: I was running into this problem with this solution: (into-array ["/tmp" 0])

IllegalArgumentException array element type mismatch  java.lang.reflect.Array.set (Array.java:-2)

Comment: @Istvan Are you sure you want to stick strings and ints in the same array?

Comment: How else would you be able to insert into a table with integer and text fields?

Comment: @Istvan If that's what you want, try `(into-array Object ["/temp" 0])`. You need to specify the base class if the elements are different types.

Comment: Yep I have updated your answer with that. You actually need to use (into-array Object args)