# Calling java function with optional parameters from Clojure

Tags: java, constructor, clojure, optional-parameters

I want to use [mXparser](https://github.com/mariuszgromada/MathParser.org-mXparser) from clojure which has an Expression Java class with multiple constructors:

1. ```
   public Expression(PrimitiveElement...elements) { ... }
   ```
2. ```
   public Expression(String expressionString, PrimitiveElement...elements) { ... }
   ```

In Java I can create new instance with a String argument:

```
Expression e = new Expression("1+2");
```

I assume it is using the second constructor because the first argument is string and the second is optional.

Now I want to do the same in clojure:

```
(Expression. "1+2")
```

It fails with

```
java.lang.String cannot be cast to [Lorg.mariuszgromada.math.mxparser.PrimitiveElement;
```

Looks like it is trying to use the first constructor which is not what I want.

How can I create a new instance of this class in Clojure only with a string argument?

Comment: You have to specify the varargs argument, https://stackoverflow.com/q/11702184.

Answer (score 1):

According to the comment from [glts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/329063/glts) it works in this way:

```
(Expression. "1+2" (into-array PrimitiveElement []))
```