# No matching method with Clojure Java interop using reify

Tags: clojure, clojure-java-interop

I have a misunderstanding about a certain Clojure/Java interop.

I'm using the Pi4J library and I want to get a listener on a GPIO Pin.

The usage documentation: https://pi4j.com/1.2/usage.html (under "Listen for Pin Changes") gives the following example:

```java
public static class GpioUsageExampleListener implements GpioPinListenerDigital {
    @Override
    public void handleGpioPinDigitalStateChangeEvent(GpioPinDigitalStateChangeEvent event) {
        // display pin state on console
        System.out.println(" --> GPIO PIN STATE CHANGE: " + event.getPin() + " = "
                + event.getState());
    }
}

// create and register gpio pin listener
myButton.addListener(new GpioUsageExampleListener());
```

There is also an example application: https://pi4j.com/1.2/example/listener.html

Which has:

```java
myButton.addListener(new GpioPinListenerDigital() {
    @Override
    public void handleGpioPinDigitalStateChangeEvent(GpioPinDigitalStateChangeEvent event) {
        // display pin state on console
        System.out.println(" --> GPIO PIN STATE CHANGE: " + event.getPin() + " = " + event.getState());
    }
});
```

So, I'm trying the following bit of Clojure code:

```clj
(import [com.pi4j.io.gpio GpioFactory GpioPinDigitalInput PinPullResistance RaspiPin]
        [com.pi4j.io.gpio.event GpioPinListenerDigital])

(def gpio (GpioFactory/getInstance))
(def mybutton (.provisionDigitalInputPin gpio RaspiPin/GPIO_02 PinPullResistance/PULL_DOWN))

(def gpio-listener (reify GpioPinListenerDigital
                    (handleGpioPinDigitalStateChangeEvent [this event]
                      (println "GPIO Event Occured"))))

(.addListener mybutton gpio-listener)
```

But I get:

```
No matching method addListener found taking 1 args for class com.pi4j.io.gpio.impl.GpioPinImpl
```

Using reflection, I have a look at the methods available to the mybutton instance, and I can see the method is there:

```clj
(clojure.reflect/reflect mybutton)

 :members
 #{{ 
    ;;; Stuff trimmed
   {:name addListener,
    :return-type void,
    :declaring-class com.pi4j.io.gpio.impl.GpioPinImpl,
    :parameter-types [java.util.List],
    :exception-types [],
    :flags #{:public :synchronized}}
   {:name addListener,
    :return-type void,
    :declaring-class com.pi4j.io.gpio.impl.GpioPinImpl,
    :parameter-types [com.pi4j.io.gpio.event.GpioPinListener<>],
    :exception-types [],
    :flags #{:varargs :public :synchronized}}}}
```

I've checked the type of gpio-listener against GpioPinListener with success.

```clj
(cast com.pi4j.io.gpio.event.GpioPinListener gpio-listener)
#object[user$reify__7404 0x11251bd "user$reify__7404@11251bd"]
```

I tried type hinting the parameter to GpioPinListener, but I get the same result.

My lack of Clojure and Java knowledge is failing me here, so I'm a little lost where to look next, but I'm sure it's something really basic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't test this, but if you note [the docs](https://pi4j.com/1.2/apidocs/com/pi4j/io/gpio/impl/GpioPinImpl.html), you'll see that `addListener` is actually var-arg, and dealing with var-arg methods can be confusing  [due to misunderstandings of how var-arg methods in Java work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11702184/how-to-handle-java-variable-length-arguments-in-clojure) .

`addListener` is expecting an *array* of listeners (which is sugared away by Java var-arg syntax). Try

```
(.addListener mybutton
              (into-array [gpio-listener]))
```

Or, since `addListener` actually has a `List` overload, this may work too

```
(.addListener myButton [gpio-listener])
```

Comment: Both work. :)

I had not noticed the var-args at all. I'll have to remember it in the future. Thank you!